# Как подключить функцию Delphi XE

Tags: delphi

В данный код:

```
....................................
while not eof(ft) do
 begin
  readln(ft,s);
 Len := Length(S);
  Pos1 := 0;
 for P := Len downto 1 do
begin
 While Pos('  ',s)<>0 do
  if S[P] = ' ' then
  begin
    if Pos1 = 0 then
    begin
      Pos1 := P;
    end
    else
    begin
    Delete(S, P, Pos1 - P + 1);
      Pos1 := 0;
    end;

  end;
end;
writeln(ft2,s)
  end;
 end;
closefile(ft);
closefile(ft2);
end;
end;
```

Подключить вот эту функцию:

```
function test(s:string):string;
var  p1,p2:Word;
begin
repeat
p1:=Pos('test1',s);
p2:=Pos('test2',s);
Delete(s,p1,p2-p1+5);
until (p1=0)or(p2=0);
Result:=s;
end;
```

Comment: А в чем вопрос? Вызывайте ее в нужном вам месте `s := test(s)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внесите ее над var в главной программе. Вот так :

```
function test(s:string):string;
var  p1,p2:Word;
begin
repeat
p1:=Pos('test1',s);
p2:=Pos('test2',s);
Delete(s,p1,p2-p1+5);
until (p1=0)or(p2=0);
Result:=s;
end;

var
    ft, ft2: TextFile;
    i, p, Len, Pos1: integer;
    s:string;
    p : integer;


begin
if OpenDialog1.Execute then begin
  AssignFile(ft, OpenDialog1.FileName);
  Reset(ft);
....................................
while not eof(ft) do
 begin
  readln(ft,s);
 Len := Length(S);
  Pos1 := 0;
 for P := Len downto 1 do
begin
 While Pos('  ',s)<>0 do
  if S[P] = edit2.text then
  begin
    if Pos1 = 0 then
    begin
      Pos1 := P;
    end
    else
    begin
    Delete(S, P, Pos1 - P + 1);
      Pos1 := 0;
    end;

  end;
end;
writeln(ft2,s)
  end;
 end;
closefile(ft);
closefile(ft2);
end;
end.
```